# QPlainTextEdit - setViewportMargins, protected

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

I have a simple app with text edit - QPlainTextEdit, created by qt designer. I just need from mainwindow.cpp setViewportMargins.But I get the following error message - void QAbstractScrollArea::setViewportMargins(int, int, int, int)' is protected.

Code:

```
ui->textEdit->setViewportMargins(10,10,10,10);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: where did you call this function? please give more info

Comment: From manwindow.cpp file. I just need to change margin of textEdit by time, from mainwindow.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected functions can only be used within the class, so it generates the error. I have solved it by designing the `CustomPlainText` class and promoting it to the original `QPlainTextEdit`, inside it I have used `setViewportMargins (10,10,10,10);`. If you want to access that function from outside the class I have created the functions `CustomSetViewportMargins({args})`.

Right click and select: **Promote to..**

[image]

Write the name of the class and the header and add it.

[image]

And press promote.

[image]

**customplaintext.cpp**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMPLAINTEXT_H
#define CUSTOMPLAINTEXT_H

#include <QPlainTextEdit>

class CustomPlainText:public QPlainTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomPlainText(QWidget * parent = 0);
    void CustomSetViewportMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
    void CustomSetViewportMargins(const QMargins & margins);
};

#endif // CUSTOMPLAINTEXT_H
```

**customplaintext.h**

```
#include "customplaintext.h"

CustomPlainText::CustomPlainText(QWidget *parent): QPlainTextEdit(parent)
{
    setViewportMargins(10,10,10,10);
}

void CustomPlainText::CustomSetViewportMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    setViewportMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
}

void CustomPlainText::CustomSetViewportMargins(const QMargins & margins)
{
    setViewportMargins(margins);
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Complete Code:** https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/CustomPlainTextProject

Comment: Thanks for answere. I need to change margin by time. So from mainwindow.cpp call function with parameter which has value of right margin. Is it possible?

Comment: @charles 
Of course it is possible, just write a function and these parameters will be sent to the protected function. In a few moments I will add those functions

Comment: Thanks. I added     CustomPlainText customText; customText.CustomSetViewportMargins(10,10,10,10); into mainwindow.cpp file and nothing happened (margin still 0). I am pretty new in qt and c++.

Comment: @charles I have uploaded the complete code to https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/CustomPlainTextProject

Answer (score 1):

In order to use protected methods of a `QPlainTextEdit` you need to subclass it, something like this:

```
class MyPlainTextEdit: public QPlainTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyPlainTextEdit(QWidget* parent=0):QPlainTextEdit(parent){}
    //ADD A PUBLIC METHOD
    void publicSetViewportMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        setViewportMargins(left ,top, right, bottom);
    }
    //OR
protected:
    void setViewportMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        //REIMPLEMENT METHOD HERE
    }
};
```